# Show, that $L$ is not regular but satisfies the pumping-property.

Tags: computer-science, regular-language, pumping-lemma

> Show, that $L_{1}:=L\left((a \cup b)^{*} \cdot(a a \cup b b) \cdot(a \cup b)^{*}\right) \cup\left\{w \in\{a, b\}^{*}\mid \lvert w \rvert \text { is prime number}\right\}$ is not regular but satisfies the pumping-property/lemma of regular languages.

Let $n=3$ be the pumping-length of $w$. Now we consider an arbitrary word $w=w_1w_2\dots w_{\lvert w\rvert}\in L$ with $\lvert w\rvert \geq3$.

- Case 1: $aa$ is a substring of $w$

  - Case 1a: $w$ begins with $aa$
    We can chose $x=aa$, $y=w_3$ and $z=w_4\dots w_{\lvert w\rvert}$ and we can pump up $y$.
  - Case 1b: $w$ does not begin with $aa$
    We can chose $x=\lambda$, $y=w_1$ and $z=w_2\dots w_{\lvert w\rvert}$, $aa\in z$ and we can pump up $y$.
- Case 2: $bb$ is a substring of $w$
  This case is analogue to Case 1
- Case 3: Not Case 1 and not Case 2, which means, that $w$ does not contain $aa$ or $bb$ and the length of $w$ must be a prime number. In other words, every $a$ gets followed by $b$ and vice versa.

  - Case 3a: $w$ begins with $a$
    Now my problem is, that I don't know how to choose $x,y,z\in\Sigma^*$ in order to satisfy Case 3a. I even doubt, that this language satisfies the pumping-property anyway, but since the question is to prove that it indeed has the pumping property, I'm not really sure how to go on now. I would appreciate some hints and corrections if possible.
  - Case 3b: $w$ does not begin with $a$
    See above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**. Let $A = \{a,b\}$. Note that the complement of the language $A^*(aa + bb)A^*$ is the set of words containing neither two consecutive $a$'s, nor two consecutive $b$'s, that is 
$$(1+b)(ab)^*(1+a).$$ 
It follows that your language is equal to $L_1 + L_2$ where
$$
L_1 = A^*(aa + bb)A^* \quad \text{and} \quad L_2 = \{u \in (1+b)(ab)^*(1+a) \mid |u| \text{ is prime }\}
$$
You have already seen that you can pump a word of $L_1$ and stay in $L_1$. For a word in $L_2$, you can take a factorisation $w = xyz$ where $y = a$ or $y = b$.
When you pump $y$, you obtain at least two consecutive $a$'s or $b$'s. In other words, you are back in $L_1$ and hence in $L$.

Comment: I only need to find one factorisation, right? That's why it's enough to say that it works for $y=a$ or $y=b$. What I understood so far: I split my language into two sublanguages which are equal to the whole language. Now I already showed that the first language satisfies the PL. Now I only need to show, that the second language satisfies it too. I take a factorisation where the $y$ part contains a or b's and pump them up to get into the first language. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, this is right.

Comment: How do I show, that it's not regular tho?

Comment: Consider $L \cap (ab)^*$.

Comment: Would $L\cap (ab)^*$ equal $\left\{w \in\{a, b\}^{*}\mid \lvert w \rvert \text { is Prime}\right\}$ or do I completely miss something? Because $aa$ and $bb$ can't be in that language, because for every $a$, we write a $b$, so it must be the second part of the Union.

Comment: This is correct.

Comment: Ok, I understood everything. Thank you

Comment: You're welcome.